# Keras Error: Error when checking model target: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I'm following https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/basic_classification to solve a Kaggle challenge.

However, I don't understand what kind of data should I feed into the fit function.

I splitted the training dataset to `X_train`, `y_train`, `X_test`, and `y_test`. `X_train` has shape of `(13125, 32, 32, 3)`.

```
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(32, 32, 3)),
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam', 
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=5)
```

I got the an error:

> Error when checking model target: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 1 array(s), but instead got the following list of 13125 arrays:

UPDATE:

```
# TensorFlow and tf.keras
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

# Helper libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(32,32,3)),
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam', 
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])


X_train_stack = np.vstack(X_train)
model.fit(X_train_stack, y_train, epochs=5)
```

I got an error:

> Error when checking input: expected flatten_7_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (420000, 32, 3)

```
#read in training set
train_img = []
train_lb = []
for i in range(len(cactus_label)):
    row = cactus_label.iloc[i]
    fileName = row['id']
    train_lb.append(row['has_cactus'])
    path = "../input/train/train/{}".format(fileName)
    im = mpimg.imread(path)
    train_img.append(im)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(train_img, train_lb) 
X_train = np.array(X_train)
X_test = np.array(X_test)
```

Comment: Can you please add how you created `X_train` and all, it seems the problem is there.

Comment: Note that i changed from `vstack()` to `stack()`

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass numpy array but you're passing a list of numpy arrays instead. Use `np.stack()` to create a single numpy array from a list of numpy arrays:

```py
X_train = np.stack(X_train, axis=0)
```